# What is the generic name for "form element" in design

Tags: forms, definition

Forms and form elements are common in application design.

So I guess there must be a name identifiying it more precisely, and that designates any kind of "form element", shall it be a combobox, an input, radio- or checkboxes.

Which one do you use or hear in your professional environment ?

Comment: We refer to them as form controls. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Looks like ! Then can talk about "controls" solely or is the context "form controls" needed ?

Comment: they are "form controls", controls is too generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the form elements mentioned by you are used. But forms and form elements mainly names as per their functionality.

For example:

If you designing a Login on form then it is simply known as Login form.
Similarly buttons or other input fields.

Ideally it should be like less confusing and just by knowing the name someone should know the functionality of the form and form element.

Comment: "form" is the generic name for "login form", "order form", etc. But what is the generic name for its elements ? "element"doesn't sound as a good choice.

Comment: You can call it controls. This is classified into different categories again. Like input controls and output controls in general. In work environment "controls" is the generic name.